# Get Entries within a Category Group with no duplicates in each category

Tags: templating

How would I loop through all categories in a group to get this scenario:

- Get 4 entries per category
- No duplicates across any of the categories, if it's in Cat 1, should not show in any other.
- Category info (title, URL, etc)

So here is a visual:

Category 1

- Entry 1
- Entry 2
- Entry 3
- Entry 4

Category 2

- <strike>Entry 1</strike> (duplicate from Category 1, do not want here, so get 4 different)
- Entry 5
- Entry 6
- Entry 7
- Entry 8

Category 3

- <strike>Entry 2</strike> (duplicate from Category 1, do not want here, so get 4 different)
- <strike>Entry 6</strike> (duplicate from Category 2, do not want here, so get 4 different)
- Entry 9
- Entry 10
- Entry 11
- Entry 12

I hope this gives a decent visual of what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this with some of my own content and believe it works to your spec. You need to keep a track of all entries that have been displayed so far. You then loop through each categories related entries and if the entry hasn't been shown in a previous category we add it to a new array within that category loop.

```
    // Set empty array to hold id's of all currently displayed entries
    {% set entries_displayed = [] %}

    // Loop over a category group
    {% for category in craft.categories.group( 'productBrand' ) %}
      <h2>{{ category.title }}</h2>

      // Get related entries to the category
      {% set related_entries = craft.entries.relatedTo( category ) %}

      // Set empty array to hold id's of entries we'll eventually output
      {% set entries_to_display = [] %}

      // Loop through related entries
      {% for entry in related_entries %}

        // If the entry hasn't been displayed
        {% if entry.id not in entries_displayed %}

          // We want to show the entry
          {% set entries_to_display = entries_to_display|merge([entry.id]) %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

      // Finally grab the entries to display from the array of id's that haven't already been shown
      {% set entries = craft.entries.id( entries_to_display ).limit( 4 ) %}
      {% for entry in entries %}

        // Add the id to our "already displayed" array
        {% set entries_displayed = entries_displayed|merge([entry.id]) %}

        {{ entry.id }} - {{ entry.title }}<br>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Erik later discovered an error in my original answer where I was setting `entries_displayed` in the first `for` loop before they'd actually been output in the last `for` loop. I've updated the code to reflect his fix.

> I had to move the `entries_displayed` array to the last `for` loop which displayed the entries. That way I knew exactly what entries had been displayed. If I didn't do that, it would assume more than 4 were shown per category.

Comment: This is so close! For some reason, one category doesn't get any entries. There are 4 categories and the 3rd is the issue. There are no expiration dates and all the entries are live. I can't imagine what the issue may be. Thank you btw!

Comment: Is it in the same category group? Have you checked there are any related entries returned?

Comment: I believe I figured it out. I will post an update with my code. I moved the `entries_displayed` array to the last for loop which displays the entries. By doing that, I'm guaranteeing only the ones displayed get merged into that array.

Comment: @Erik - The problem with that is that there are no initial entries to show because `entries_to_display` is empty. I will test with the limit 4 issue and update my answer.

Comment: Hmm... it works though. Test my code.

Comment: Ignore me.. I originally had to test with products not entries. Your code works ;)

Comment: Awesome! I marked yours as the answer with my edit. Thanks again!